# Use keyup event in ZK

Tags: events, keyevent, zk

I would like to use te keyup event in ZK.

I had found that you can do it with this event.

```
        tbxNumeroIdentificacion.addEventListener(Events.ON_CHANGING, new EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(Event evento) throws Exception {
                 InputEvent inputEvent = (InputEvent) evento;
                 String currentValue = inputEvent.getValue();
                 System.out.println(currentValue);
            }
        });
```